# Is it better to import static or dynamic with I/O Bound application

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have been working on a I/O bound application which is a web crawler for news. I have one file where I start the script which we can call "monitoring.py" and by choosing which news company I want to monitor I add a parameter e.g. `monitoring.py --company=sydsvenskan` which will then trigger sydsvenskan webcrawling.

What it does is basically this:

**scraper.py**

```
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import ClassVar, Dict

import requests

from lib.vendors.sydsvenskan import sydsvenskan
from lib.vendors.bbc import bbc


class Scraper:
    scrapers: ClassVar[Dict[str, Scraper]] = {}
    domain: ClassVar[str]

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        Scraper.scrapers[cls.domain] = cls

    @classmethod
    def for_url(cls, domain, url) -> Scraper:
        return cls.scrapers[domain](url)

    @abstractmethod
    def scrape_feed(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def scrape_product(self):
        pass


class SydsvenskanScraper(Scraper):
    domain = 'sydsvenskan'

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def scrape_feed(self):
        with requests.get(self.url) as rep:
            # FIXME Better way than this atleast :P
            if rep:
                return sydsvenskan().scrape_feed(rep=rep)

    def scrape_product(self):
        with requests.get(self.url) as rep:
            # FIXME Better way than this atleast :P
            if rep:
                return sydsvenskan().scrape_product(rep=rep)


class BBCScraper(Scraper):
    domain = 'bbc'

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def scrape_feed(self):
        with requests.get(self.url) as rep:
            # FIXME Better way than this atleast :P
            if rep:
                return bbc().scrape_feed(rep=rep)

    def scrape_product(self):
        with requests.get(self.url) as rep:
            # FIXME Better way than this atleast :P
            if rep:
                return bbc().scrape_product(rep=rep)
```

---

**sydsvenskan.py**

```
    from __future__ import annotations
    
    from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser
  
    
    @attr.dataclass
    class Info:
      """Scraped info about product"""
      all_articles: set = attr.ib(factory=set)
      store: str = attr.ib(factory=str)
      name: Optional[str] = attr.ib(factory=str)
      image: Optional[str] = attr.ib(factory=str)

    class sydsvenskan():
        def scrape_feed(self, rep):
            doc = HTMLParser(rep.text)
    
            all_products = {
                f"https://www.sydsvenskan.se{product_link.attrs['href']}" for product_link in
                doc.css('td.search-articles > a, div.product-image > a')
            }
    
            return Info(
                store="sydsvenskan",
                all_products=all_products
            )
    
        def scrape_article(self, rep):
            doc = HTMLParser(rep.text)
    
            name = "Test"
            price = "Test"
            image = "Test"
    
            return Info(
                store="Sydsvenskan",
                name=name,
                price=price,
                image=image,
            )
```

However my problem is that I do not know if its better to add static imports of all stores that I will in the future will monitor (Which can be up to 40 news companies) or if its better to use dynamic import to only import the one that we call from parameter. (I do believe the problem if I use dynamic import, I cannot get help from pycharm when we use dataclass from `class Info` e.g. `xxxx.price`, `xxxx.name` etc etc)

So my question is, what would be better for me. To import all the stores as static or use the dynamic for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universal answer for performance questions is : measure **then** decide.

You ask two questions.

### Would it be faster to use dynamic imports ?

I would think so, but in a very negligeable way. Except if the computer running this code is very constrained, the difference would be barely noticeable (on the order of <1 second at startup time, and a few dozens of megabytes of RAM).

You can test it quickly by duplicating your `sydsvenskan.py` file 40 times, importing each of them in your `scraper.py` and running `time python scraper.py` before and after.

And in general, prefer doing simple things. Static imports are simpler than dynamic ones.

### Can PyCharm still provide code insights even if the import is dynamic ?

Simply put : yes. I tested to put it in a function and it worked fine :

```py
# file: bbc_scraper.py
class BBCScraper:
    def scrape(self) -> str:
        return "bar"
```

```py
# file: main.py
def run_scraper_for_bbc():
    import bbc_scraper
    scraper = bbc_scraper.BBCScraper()
    print(scraper.scrape())
```

Comment: I really appreciate that you have gave me an answer for what I have been looking for few days! :)